# Continuity of a linear mapping and boudedness on the unit ball

Tags: analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

I would like to show the following : $(E,\lVert\rVert_{E})$ and $(V,\lVert\rVert_{V})$ are two normed vector spaces.

Consider $f : E\to V$ a linear mapping, if $f$ is continuous at $0_{E}$ then $\lVert f(x)\rVert_{V}$ is bounded  for $x$ in the unit ball of $E$.

My attempt : By the continuity of $f$ at $0_{E}$ we have

$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,\forall x\in E : \lVert x\rVert_{E}\leq\delta\implies\lVert f(x)\rVert_{V}\leq\epsilon$

Fix $\epsilon =1$. Then there exists $\delta$ such that $\lvert x\rVert_{E}\leq\delta\implies\lVert f(x)\rVert_{V}\leq 1$.

But for all $x$ in the unit ball of $E$ we have $\lVert x\rVert_{E}\leq 1\implies\lVert\delta x\rVert_{E}\leq\delta\implies\lVert f(x)\rVert_{V}\leq\frac{1}{\delta}$

Using the linearity of $f$

Is this correct and have you an other way to prove this ? Thank you a lot !

Comment: Yes, it is 100% correct.

Comment: Your argument is correct. Another way of showing it would be: the image of a compact set under a continuous function is compact, so the image of the unit ball must also be compact (hence bounded).

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answers ! @nigel Yes this is a good argument indeed ! But it is valid in the case where $E$ and $V$ are finite dimensional vector spaces ?

Comment: This result gives us the existence of $M$ such that $\lVert f(x)\rVert_{V}\leq M$ (through the existence of an $\delta$ for $\epsilon =1$) but it does not tell us how to find this $M$, it must be case by case according to the function $f$ ? Because sometimes using the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of the continuity to find the good $\delta$ can be really tedious no ?